# Json parsing - how to grab data that is only in brackets

Tags: php, json

Here is my code:

```
{
  "604377": {
    "competitors": {
      "3521278": {
        "Name": "Brazil",
        "Jockey": null,
        "Weight": null,
        "Saddle": 0,
        "Barrier": null,
        "QLDWin": 0,
        "VICWin": 0,
        "NSWWin": 0,
        "QLDPlace": 0,
        "VICPlace": 0,
        "NSWPlace": 0,
        "DetailedPricing": {
```

Does anyone know how to get the actual number in the brackets: "604377". I can grab the other fields as they are specified but struggling with this. I am using php.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're looking for but you can use sa `foreach` loop to get keys and values

Comment: You can iterate with `for...in`.

Answer (score 2):

```
print_r(array_keys(json_decode($json, true)));
```

Output:

```
[0] => 604377
```

[**fiddle**](http://codepad.org/reCkWRiB)

Answer (score 0):

That is actually what might be considered a poorly formed data structure in that you have what amount to values you are interested in stored as keys.  Since these values can likely be variable, you are forced to use inspect the keys for the value you want.

So say you are using PHP:

```
$object = json_decode($your_json_string);
$array_of_obj_properties = get_object_vars($object);
foreach($array_of_obj_properties as $prop) {
    // figure out what to do with $prop
}
```

Or if you need to get at the number inside of `competitors`

```
$object = json_decode($your_json_string);
$outer_object_properties = get_object_vars($object);
foreach($outer_object_properties as $prop) {
    $competitors_props = get_object_vars($outer_object_properties->{$prop}->competitors);
    foreach($competitors_props as $comp_prop) {
        // do something with $comp_prop
    }   
}
```

As you can see, that is a vary unwieldy structure.  If you control of the data structure that is JSON-encoded, you might consider changing it to something that gives you a known key at which to access these values.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to get the first key, you can iterate through the result of `json_decode`:

```
$firstKey = null;

$json = json_decode($jsonString);
foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
    $firstKey = $key;
    break; //make sure we don't bother to iterate through the rest of the object
}

var_dump($firstKey); //This will be your relevant key
```